# How to $compile the value when using ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

```html
<ul class="alert alert-link alert-info"
    data-ng-show="messages">
    <li data-ng-repeat="msg in messages" data-ng-bind-html="msg | unsafe"></li>
</ul>
```

The controller code looks as below:

```js
...
var msg = 'You\'re logged in. The registration must ' +
           + 'be <a href="#" ' + 
           + 'data-ng-click="logout(\'/ajax/logout/\', $event)">logout</a> of your profile.';
$scope.messages = [msg];
...
```

How to `$compile` a `msg`, if `msg` comes from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's a really really terrible idea to compile things in angular directly from your backend. You can usually tell that if you're written the word `unsafe` in your code, you are putting yourself at risk. Not to mention it's going to be hard to find issues with the code if the code is on some other server/model/database somewhere. You should just return a model you can use from your server.

If you must do this, you'll probably want to create a directive which has something like `element.html($compile(msg)(scope))` in your link function.

Comment: This is i18n-message, which is stored in a static file on backend.   
Are your solution, throws an error: `Error: [$sce:itype]...`

[**plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sZARES?p=preview)

I'd still like via `ng-repeat`, but not with `html()`, `append()`,...

Comment: In general, stopped on the use of directives, instead of `ng-repeat`: `element.html($compile('<li>' + messages.join('</li><li>') + '</li>')($scope));`